# Importing ES6 Class under a different name

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Using [gulp, browserify & babelify](http://problematic.io/2015/02/26/using-babel-and-browserify-with-gulp/), exporting/import classes worked fine until I tried to import the same class under a different name:

```
// Acme/DefaultInit.js
export default class DefaultInit {
    constructor() {
        console.log('hello');
    }
}

// App/Init.js
import * as B from "../Acme/DefaultInit";

class Init extends B.DefaultInit {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log('how are you?');
    }
}
```

So when I run the gulp built script, the error is:

```
TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined
```

coming from the babel generated code

```
if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass); }
```

What I'm doing wrong there ? Note that are no jslint errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're exporting `DefaultInit` as a default so it'll actually be available from `B.default` not `B.DefaultInit`.

If you want to be able to do `B.DefaultInit` drop the `default` from before `class DefaultInit` or alternatively replace `import * as B` to `import DefaultInit`.